# Axiom Of Completeness Equivalence

Tags: real-analysis

Let assume there for every non empty $A,B:A\prec B$ there is $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ so that $A\prec \{x_0\}\prec B$

It is said that this is equivalent to the axiom of completeness, I understand that:

 1. $\forall a\in A:a\leq x_0 \rightarrow x_0$ is an upper bound of A, and $B$ is also an upper bound (by definition)
 1. on the other side $\forall b\in B:x_0\leq b \rightarrow x_0 $ is a lower bound of $B$ therefore from $1$ and $2$ we can conclude that $supA=x_0 $ which is the axiom of completeness.

Am I missing something? or it is a straightforward claim (using the properties of a field and its order relation)?

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming that $A\prec B$ means that $a\le b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. To prove that the statement is equivalent to completeness of $\Bbb R$, you must prove two things: that the statement implies completeness, and that completeness implies the statement. What you’ve written looks like an attempt at the first of these implications, but as it stands it really doesn’t make much sense.

You’re assuming that whenever $A$ and $B$ are non-empty subsets of $\Bbb R$ such that $A\prec B$ there is an $x_0\in\Bbb R$ such that $A\prec\{x_0\}\prec B$. You want to prove that $\sup A$ exists whenever $A$ is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$ that is bounded above. Your first step, therefore, should be:

> Let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$ that has an upper bound, say $b_0$.

In order to apply your hypothesis, you need some other non-empty set $B$ such that $A\prec B$. The hypothesis will then give you an $x_0$ such that $A\prec\{x_0\}\prec B$, and you’d like to choose $B$ in such a way that you can prove that this $x_0$ is the supremum of $A$. There is a natural candidate for this $B$:

> Let $B=\{x\in\Bbb R:a\le b\text{ for all }a\in A\}$; $b_0\in B$, so $B\ne\varnothing$, and by definition $A\prec B$. By hypothesis, therefore, there is an $x_0\in\Bbb R$ such that $A\prec\{x_0\}\prec B$.

Now we need to prove that this $x_0$ actually does the job.

> Clearly $a\le x_0$ for each $a\in A$, so $x_0\in B$: $x_0$ is at least *an* upper bound for $A$. If $b$ is any upper bound for $A$, then $b\in B$, so $x_0\le b$, so $x_0$ is in fact the *least* upper bound for $A$; i.e., $x_0=\sup A$. Since $A$ was arbitrary, this shows that $\Bbb R$ is complete.

That, I think, is the argument that you were trying to make.

We still have to prove the opposite implication, so assume that $\Bbb R$ is complete, and let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty subsets of $\Bbb R$ such that $A\prec B$; we must show that there is an $x_0\in\Bbb R$ such that $A\prec\{x_0\}\prec B$. An obvious candidate is $\sup A$, if we can show that it exists. We know that $A$ is non-empty, so all that remains to check is that $A$ is bounded above. This isn’t hard: $B$ is non-empty, so there is some $b\in B$, and by hypothesis $a\le b$ for each $a\in A$, so $A$ is bounded above by $b$. By hypothesis, then, $\sup A$ exists; call it $x_0$. Clearly $a\le x_0$ for each $a\in A$, so $A\prec\{x_0\}$. On the other hand, each $b\in B$ is an upper bound for $A$, and $x_0$ is the least upper bound, so $x_0\le b$ for each $b\in B$, i.e., $\{x_0\}\prec B$. This complete the proof.